# How to debug deployed Grails application

Tags: debugging, grails, ide, intellij-idea

Is there any way to debug Grails application *deployed* to production server in Intellij IDEA or any other IDE?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to start your server in debug mode by adding something like this to the java process start script:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then in IntelliJ open `Run > Edit Configurations` and select `Defaults > Remote`, where you can set the port you specified above to debug the remote JVM.

You can do the same in Eclipse.

Comment: You probably want `suspend=n` so it doesn't hang on start but accepts connections on-demand

Comment: One of the nice places that above can be set is the GRAILS_OPTS (e.g. stackoverflow.com/a/18599827/1572286).

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use `grails-debug run-app` to debug Grails application. But I think it's not good choice for production

Comment: Just for the record, since grails 2.4.0 the command is slightly different: `grails -debug run-app`

Comment: Year 2017 update: in grails 3.2.8 it is `grails run-app --debug-jvm`. By default it listens on port 5005.

Comment: @Filip Stachowiak how to change the port when executing grails run-app --debug-jvm ?

Answer (score 3):

Also, starting from grails 2.3.0 the jvm is forked into the build vm and the application vm. Using `--debug` allow you to debug the build vm, and using `--debug-fork` allows you to debug the app vm. [Grails 2.3 forked execution](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode)